# How to implement password confirmation before updating data

Tags: php

The goal is to create profile settings page, where users can change their email address, but before updating ask them to enter their password.

So, I need to fetch password from database and compare it to password entered by user, and if they match update email address.

But, when I try to implement logic, I get a blank page. Code work till query. It stop working when $passwordCheck = true and $resultCheck = 0 (see edited below).

**Edited (2019.01.09):** redirects work till `header('Location: ../edituser.php?success=emailupdate')`. When enter new email, correct password and click submit button, it shows changeemail.php (my action script) page instead of redirect to edituser.php with success messsage. I assume that something get broken and script stuck. Also, added complete script.

**Edited (2019.01.10):** my question is: how to implement password confirmation before updating data using PHP. Above description shows how I tried to implement it. I'm looking for information about solution, different approaches to this problem or some help with my code. Sorry if I not clarify my question detailed enough. I also add profile settings picture below.

Picture 1. Profile settings page

[image: Picture 1]

changeemail.php script:

```
// Check for submit
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Get form data
    $update_id = $_POST['update_id'];
    $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
    $confirm_password = test_input($_POST['confirm_password']);

    // Store post id in session
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['update_id'] = $update_id;

    // Check for empty field
    if (empty($email)) {
        header('Location: ../edituser.php?error=emptyemail');
        exit();
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // Check email
        header('Location: ../edituser.php?error=invalidemail');
        exit();
    } else if (empty($confirm_password)) {
        header('Location: ../edituser.php?error=emptyconfirmpassword');
        exit();
    } else {
        // Check if email already exist
        $query = "SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE  email = ?";
        // Create prepared statement
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
            header('Location: ../edituser.php?error=sqlerror');
            exit();
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $email);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $email, $password);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                // Check if passwords match
                $passwordCheck = password_verify($confirm_password, $password);

                if ($passwordCheck == false) {
                    header('Location: ../edituser.php?error=wrongconfirmpassword');
                    exit();
                } else if ($passwordCheck == true && $resultCheck > 0) {
                    header('Location: ../edituser.php?error=emailtaken');
                    exit();
                }
                // Update email
                $query = "UPDATE users SET email = ? WHERE id = ?";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
                    header('Location: ../edituser.php?error=sqlerror');
                    exit();
                } else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $email, $update_id);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    header('Location: ../edituser.php?success=emailupdate');
                    exit();
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
} else {
    header('Location: ../edituser.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: "I get a blank page"  Check your error logs.  Also, you are using variables here that you are not showing being defined.  We can't really give a good answer without seeing the whole picture.

Comment: You have no logic to cover if $passwordCheck = true and $resultCheck = 0 therefore, it falls through to the lines past 'Update email' - i.e., no header redirect (so "a blank page"....).  Check your logic to do what you want.

Comment: @PatrickQ Added complete script.

Comment: @CFPSupport Added new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my issue I add another query:

```
$query = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
    header('Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror');
    exit();
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $update_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Old query won't find password for updated email, because it's not exist yet, and will close connection.

Answer (score 0):

As I said before - check your logic......

Sometimes that is best done in a 'reverse' manner - - - for instance, in this case, you say

> When enter new email, correct password and click submit button, it shows changeemail.php (my action script) page instead of redirect to edituser.php with success messsage. I assume that something get broken and script stuck.

So, in other words....

EXPECTED RESULT: redirect to edituser.php

CURRENT RESULT: shows emailupdate (this is not clear in the question, though I believe that this is the case - you are redirecting to edituser.php?success=emailupdate.  If this is not the case, clarify!  My example below will presume this....)

So, let's follow the logic...... (remove all non-logic and/or redirection code to find why it is hitting where it is....)

First, let's look at why it isn't going where you want......

(EXPECTED RESULT: redirect to edituser.php)

Removing all code except what you expect, we get

```
// Check for submit
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // DO ALL SORTS OF STUFF
} else {
    // NEVER SELECT THIS IF THERE IS A 'SUBMIT' POSTED
    header('Location: ../edituser.php');
    exit();
}
```

However, to get to this page, you HAVE a 'submit', so the 'expected' line will NEVER be selected!

Now, let's look at what IS happening - and why......

```
// Check for submit
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Get form data
    $update_id = $_POST['update_id'];
    $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
    $confirm_password = test_input($_POST['confirm_password']);


    // Check for empty field
    if (empty($email)) {
        // WE HAVE EMAIL, SO THIS IS NOT HIT
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // Check email
        // EMAIL IS OK, SO NOT HIT
    } else if (empty($confirm_password)) {
        // PASSWORD IS OK, SO NOT HIT
    } else {

        // EMAIL FOUND SO WE ARE HERE

            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                // Check if passwords match
                $passwordCheck = password_verify($confirm_password, $password);

                if ($passwordCheck == false) {
                    // PASSWORD IS OK, SO NO HIT
                } else if ($passwordCheck == true && $resultCheck > 0) {
                    // OK, SO NO HIT
                }
                // Update email
                $query = "UPDATE users SET email = ? WHERE id = ?";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
                    // NO FAILED SQL, SO NO HIT
                } else {
                   // NO OTHER LOGIC, SO THIS _WILL_ BE A HIT........
                   // *****************************************
                   header('Location: ../edituser.php?success=emailupdate');
                   exit();
                   // *****************************************
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Again, it is clear from your code that you will get the results you describe.

What I'm not sure of is really what you are expecting to do (so I can't really recommend code for you), though certainly the logic you are using is taking you where you are telling it to go - even though it is not what you would like to happen.....

You may need an additional check somewhere (to determine if you really need to update the email or just send them to the edituser page, etc.) - though you have to get the logic straight!

Hopefully this will show you a couple ways you can break down the code to get where you are wanting to go.  I often START writing code with comments - then go back and fill in the logic with code.  This both gives a simple way to follow along with the steps and gives well commented code for later debugging.  I highly suggest you use such a system for your coding - certainly when starting out it is useful, but having well commented code will serve you well throughout your life.